# Get an URL from text surrounded with curly braces using PHP Regular expression

Tags: php, regex

I have the following text (inside some more text):
{movie:http://www.film.com/films/film1}

I would like to use a regular expression to get the url based on the fact that it's wrapped inside curly braces and contains "movie:" after the first brace. How can I do this using PHP?

Comment: Has it one or multiples URLs?

Comment: Thats almost like a JSON string except key and value must be in quotes. Do you generate that string yourself or do you get it from somwhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$t = "{movie:http://www.film.com/films/film1}";
preg_match(/{movie:([^}]+)}/,$t,$m);
$url = $m[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if (preg_match('/\{movie:(.*?)}/', $text, $match))
    print "Found movie URL '".$match[1]."'\n";
```